# Model using many models (Django)

Tags: django, django-models

I have a project where a Monster can have many Actions, but I don't want to relate the Action to any particular Monster. How can I do that? The code is as follows:

Monsters(I divided that way so I can expand and create a Character Sheet based o the BaseSheet as well):

```
from django.db import models
from actions.models import Action

# Create your models here.
from django.utils.text import slugify


class BaseSheet(models.Model):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    race: str = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    size: str = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ac: int = models.IntegerField()
    ac_type: str = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hp: int = models.IntegerField()
    hp_dices: str = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    movement: str = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    strength: int = models.IntegerField()
    dexterity: int = models.IntegerField()
    constitution: int = models.IntegerField()
    intelligence: int = models.IntegerField()
    wisdom: int = models.IntegerField()
    charisma: int = models.IntegerField()
    languages: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="None")
    slug: str = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(f'{self.name}-{self.id}')
        return super().save()


class Monster(BaseSheet):
    challenge: str = models.CharField(default="0", max_length=3)
    description: str = models.TextField(default="")
    actions = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Action:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Action(models.Model):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description: str = models.TextField()
    is_attack: bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    weapon_type: str = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    attack: int = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    reach: str = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    hit: int = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    hit_dice: str = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    damage_type: str = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_attack:
            self.weapon_type = None
            self.attack = None
            self.reach = None
            self.hit = None
            self.hit_dice = None
            self.damage_type = None

        return super().save()
```

Edit:
I recently changed the ForeignKey to a ManyToMany in Monster. I want to a Monster to have multiple actions, but the actions can repeat other monsters. For exemple a Eagle have an action called Claw, and a Bear also has an action called Claw. When I try to access the actions that a Monster have, is appears actions.Action.None. I guess Django is not saving the actions that I put in the monsters, and I wanna know why and how to fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recently changed the ForeignKey to a ManyToMany in Monster. I want to a Monster to have multiple actions, but the actions can repeat other monsters. For exemple a Eagle have an action called Claw, and a Bear also has an action called Claw. When I try to access the actions that a Monster have, is appears actions.Action.None. I guess Django is not saving the actions that I put in the monsters, and I wanna know why and how to fix it

Comment: Maybe Django abstract models are fitting your needs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes